# TypeScript Private Interface in File

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript file like this:

```
class SomeClass {
//...
}

interface SomeInterface {
//...
}
```

I would like SomeClass to be accessible from other files, but I want SomeInterface to be accessible only from within the above file.

1. What is the simplest way to make the interface "private"?
2. I'm guessing the answer to #1 is to export SomeClass.  If I do this, is it possible to avoid rewriting all of my other project files to use import/export as well?  I've found that as soon as I start importing modules in a file, I have to start exporting modules from that file as well, at which point all files that referenced that file also have to start importing modules.

Comment: You already are using some sort of modules, right? Then everthing that is not explicitly `export`ed already *is* local to that scope by default.

Comment: You want SomeClass to be accessible by other files. So you export it.

Comment: @Bergi, no, I am not using modules.

Comment: @user1325179 Then you should start using them :-) Or use `module { }` syntax or namespaces or something like that.